# Export DataGridView to text file with header

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to export `DataGridView` to a text file. I write this code. It works fine but I want to write column headers to the textfile too.

```
SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog();
dialog.Filter = "Text File|*.txt";
var result = dialog.ShowDialog();
if (result != DialogResult.OK)
    return;
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
int rowcount = dgvSum.Rows.Count;
int columncount = dgvSum.Columns.Count;

for (int i = 0; i < rowcount - 1; i++)
{
    List<string> cols = new List<string>();
    for (int j = 0; j < columncount - 1; j++)
    {
        cols.Add(dgvSum.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString());
    }
    builder.AppendLine(string.Join("\t", cols.ToArray()));
}
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(dialog.FileName, builder.ToString());
MessageBox.Show(@"Text file was created.");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you need this line before the first `for` loop:

```
List<string> headerCols = new List<string>();
for (int j = 0; j < columncount - 1; j++)
{
    headerCols.Add(dgvSum.Columns[j].HeaderText);
}
builder.AppendLine(string.Join("\t", headerCols));

for (int i = 0; i < rowcount - 1; i++)
{
    ....
    ....
```

Comment: `ToArray()` call on List in counter-effective. Why create a new copy of data? String.Join works with any IEnumerable

Comment: @ASh...Yes. That's right. I just copied the OP's version and customized it, this is why I didn't noticed about `ToArray()`. Fixed,Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I would use built-in functionality (`GetClipboardContent()` method)

```
SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog();
dialog.Filter = "Text File|*.txt";
var result = dialog.ShowDialog();
if (result != DialogResult.OK)
    return;

// setup for export
dgvSum.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridViewClipboardCopyMode.EnableAlwaysIncludeHeaderText;
dgvSum.SelectAll();
// hiding row headers to avoid extra \t in exported text
var rowHeaders = dgvSum.RowHeadersVisible;
dgvSum.RowHeadersVisible = false;

// ! creating text from grid values
string content = dgvSum.GetClipboardContent().GetText();

// restoring grid state
dgvSum.ClearSelection();
dgvSum.RowHeadersVisible = rowHeaders;

System.IO.File.WriteAllText(dialog.FileName, content);
MessageBox.Show(@"Text file was created.");
```

Comment: The grid's MultiSelect property may be false so you will need to capture the current value, set MultiSelect = true and restore it afterwards like you did with RowHeadersVisible otherwise SelectAll will not work..